# Rendering an Ember.Checkbox with a specific ID attribute

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In Ember, what is the correct way to explicitly set the ID attribute of an `Ember.View` to something dynamic? If possible I'd like to avoid extending `Ember.View` just for this bit of functionality. Using the example below I've tried setting both 'id' and 'elementId' to something like `{{id}}` to no avail.

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id='_task'>
  <label class='for-checkbox' for="task-{{unbound id}}"></label>
  {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="complete" elementId="task-{{id}}"}}
  {{description}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <ul class='tasks'>
    {{#each tasks}}
      {{partial "task"}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing something like `{{... {{...}} ...}}` you're probably doing something wrong.

```
<label class="for-checkbox" {{bindAttr for="name"}}></label>
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="complete" nameBinding="name"}}
```

With name being a computed property on task, should do the trick.

Comment: That makes sense. However, framework idioms aside, this seems like something one would want to keep out of the Model layer. Is this type of thing typical for Ember apps?

Comment: If you want a property based on another property, you'll need a computed property, whether you place this on the model or a controller is up to you. Another option might be a handlebars helper.